# Export quiz result to a text file in Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to have questions and answers exported to a text file such as result.txt?

I answer all the questions and at the end - all the information is saved in a txt file as a list, that can be viewed later.

**Example:
Question 1
Answer 1
Question 2
Answer 2
...**

I was wondering about file=open, but would that be right?
And how do I export input questions with file open?

I hope you can help.

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

date = today.strftime("%d.may, %Y.year\n")
print("Today is:", date)


print("Greeting text 1")
print("Greeting text 2\n")

def Vide():
    
    while True:
        name = input("Let's see!\nWhat is your name? ")
        description = input("Enter a description of the environmental pollution: ")
        city = input("In which city is environmental pollution observed? ")
        address = input("Enter your residential address: ")

        try:
            
            question = int(input("Do you have any additional complaints?\nAnswer with: 1 = Yes, 2 = No\n" ))
          
        except ValueError:
            print("Answer with numbers - 1 or 2!")
            continue

       
        if question == 1:
            print("\nJYou noted that there are additional complaints, fill in the questions again!\n")
            continue
        
        elif question == 2:
            print("Thank you for your complaint, it will be resolved! ")
            break
        else:
            print("Only numbers 1 and 2 are allowed!")
          
Vide()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wanted the file content as a key-value pair, initialize a dictionary and add the corresponding values, instead of using separate variables for names, descriptions, etc. use them as dictionary keys.

First, initialize a global dictionary

```
global mydict
```

Initialize it in `Vide()` function. (use of `global` keyword because `mydict` is being modified in a function)

```
global mydict
mydict = {}
```

Store question and answer as a key-value pair

```
mydict["name"] = input("Let's see!\nWhat is your name? ")
mydict["description"] = input("Enter a description of the environmental pollution: ")
mydict["city"] = input("In which city is environmental pollution observed? ")
mydict["address"] = input("Enter your residential address: ")
```

In `try` block:

```
mydict["question"] = int(input("Do you have any additional complaints?\nAnswer with: 1 = Yes, 2 = No\n"))
```

Now the `if-else` statements:

```
if mydict["question"] == 1:
    print("\nJYou noted that there are additional complaints, fill in the questions again!\n")
    continue

elif mydict["question"] == 2:
    print("Thank you for your complaint, it will be resolved! ")
    break
else:
    print("Only numbers 1 and 2 are allowed!")
```

After calling the function `Vide()`, write your dictionary to a file

```
with open("qna.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(mydict))

f.close()
```

---

### Whole code

```
global mydict

print("Greeting text 1")
print("Greeting text 2\n")


def Vide():
    global mydict
    mydict = {}

    while True:
        mydict["name"] = input("Let's see!\nWhat is your name? ")
        mydict["description"] = input("Enter a description of the environmental pollution: ")
        mydict["city"] = input("In which city is environmental pollution observed? ")
        mydict["address"] = input("Enter your residential address: ")

        try:
            mydict["question"] = int(input("Do you have any additional complaints?\nAnswer with: 1 = Yes, 2 = No\n"))

        except ValueError:
            print("Answer with numbers - 1 or 2!")
            continue

        if mydict["question"] == 1:
            print("\nJYou noted that there are additional complaints, fill in the questions again!\n")
            continue

        elif mydict["question"] == 2:
            print("Thank you for your complaint, it will be resolved! ")
            break
        else:
            print("Only numbers 1 and 2 are allowed!")


Vide()
with open("qna.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(mydict))

f.close()
```

Comment: I just tried copy and paste your code, but i get: IndentationError: expected an indented block - This code is something new to me

Comment: This means you have to fix the indentation of your code. Go through the docs: https://www.askpython.com/python/python-indentation

Comment: I have edited my question and added the whole code, you can verify your indentation errors

Comment: Super simple. Ty, Geeky!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by writing or appending to a text file. You are correct, we can use the file = open structure to achieve this. I suggest writing something like the following:

```
file = open('results.txt', 'w')
```

Then use the following to write to the file once it has been opened.

```
file.write("Use your variables and questions from before to print user entered data")
```

Don't forget to close the file once you're done!

```
file.close()
```